# SPFieldUrl does not work

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, custom-field-types, external-list

I have an external list, items in that list have a field that contains an url. I want to show this url as a link in sharepoint form. 
I found [this example](http://zimmergren.net/misc/sp-2010-customizing-the-forms-for-external-lists-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010-by-using-custom-field-controls-and-jquery-2)
and defined in my Creator and Updater methods in BCS model:

```
          <TypeDescriptor Name="description" DefaultDisplayName="Description" TypeName="System.String" CreatorField="true" >
            <Properties>
              <Property Name="SPCustomFieldType" Type="System.String">Url</Property>
            </Properties>
          </TypeDescriptor>
```

But this does not work, Item field is shown as simple TextBox form. If I add this TypeDescriptor to SpecificFinder Method on list creation(using Client Object Model) I get a strange "Application error" exception.
Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: OK, SPCustomFieldType may be defined only in SpecificFinder method, i did so. But Exception: "Error in the Application" is still raised. What's wrong? Is that related with using ClientObject Model?